# init function not present in kallsyms

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I wrote a simple hello world kernel module

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int __init test_hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In init\n", __func__);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In exit\n", __func__);
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

After loading the module, i am checking what all symbols are added into /proc/kallsysms. I don't observe test_hello_init. Why don't we have it

```
0000000000000000 r __func__.20413   [hello]
0000000000000000 t test_hello_exit  [hello]
0000000000000000 r __func__.20417   [hello]
0000000000000000 r _note_6  [hello]
0000000000000000 d __this_module    [hello]
0000000000000000 t cleanup_module   [hello]
```

Comment: If `module_init(test_hello_init);` was never called, `test_hello_init` may have been optimized away.

Comment: 'static' means the function is not global.

Comment: test_hello_exit is static and is still present in kallsyms

Comment: i have loaded the module and its printk is present in dmesg

Comment: I think it is because the module's .init.text section gets discarded after the module init function returns.

Comment: Is the freeing memory only for builtin right

Comment: @md.jamal No, freeing init memory is also for loadable modules.

Comment: The __init macro causes the init function to be discarded and its memory freed once the init function finishes for built-in drivers, but not loadable modules
https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x281.htm

Comment: @md.jamal Here is something a bit more recent: [__init/__exit/__initdata](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kernel-hacking/hacking.html#init-exit-initdata). Quote: "similarly modules discard this memory after initialization."

Comment: @IanAbbott yep, it's definitely that, post it as an answer!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I haven't worked out where kallsyms is populated yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linux kernel 5.8 source as a reference, the module's symbol table for "kallsyms" is set up by the call to `add_kallsyms()` (in "kernel/module.c") at module load time (call path: syscall `init_module()`, `load_module()`, `post_relocation()`, `add_kallsyms()`), before the module has been fully initialized.  It adds the module's full symbol table (pointed to by the module's `kallsyms` member), and also constructs a cut-down, core symbol table (in the module's `core_kallsyms` member) for use after the module has been initialized.

The switch from the full symbol table to the core symbol table occurs at the call

```
    /* Switch to core kallsyms now init is done: kallsyms may be walking! */
    rcu_assign_pointer(mod->kallsyms, &mod->core_kallsyms);
```

from `do_init_module()` (call path: syscall `init_module()`, `load_module()`, `do_init_module()`). This occurs after the module's `init` function (if it has one) has been called.

`do_init_module()` is also responsible for discarding the module's initial memory section (containing functions marked `__init` and data marked `__initdata`) once the module is initialized successfully. This is done by adding a pointer to the module's init section to the static `init_free_list` list and scheduling a work item to free any sections on the list:

```
    freeinit = kmalloc(sizeof(*freeinit), GFP_KERNEL);
```

```
    freeinit->module_init = mod->init_layout.base;
```

```
    if (llist_add(&freeinit->node, &init_free_list))
        schedule_work(&init_free_wq);
```

The scheduled work function is `do_free_init()`. That exchanges `init_free_list` with an empty list and iterates through the original copy of `init_free_list` to free the module's initial memory section:

```
    list = llist_del_all(&init_free_list);
```

```
    llist_for_each_safe(pos, n, list) {
        initfree = container_of(pos, struct mod_initfree, node);
        module_memfree(initfree->module_init);
        kfree(initfree);
    }
```