# __init and __exit attributes for loadable kernel modules

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm confused about the usage of `__init`  and `_exit` macros for loadable kernel modules. I'm aware of it's usage for kernel modules that are built-in, but it makes no sense (at least to me) to use them while defining `entry` and `exit` functions for loadable kernel modules.

As a quick experiment, here's my silly little skeleton module

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int __init helloworld_init(void) {
    printk("\"Hello world initialization!\"\n");
    return 0;
}

static int init_wrapper(void) {
   // calling our init function here
   return helloworld_init();
}

static void __exit helloworld_exit(void) {
    printk("\"Hello world exit, let's try calling init here\"\n");
    init_wrapper();
}

module_init(helloworld_init);
module_exit(helloworld_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("AjB");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("LKM skeleton");
```

Let's grep for 'helloworld' on `/proc/kallsyms`. No mention of the `__init` function here.

```
0000000000000000 r _note_7      [helloworld]
0000000000000000 t helloworld_exit      [helloworld]
0000000000000000 d __this_module        [helloworld]
0000000000000000 t cleanup_module       [helloworld]
```

It's [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63689045/init-function-not-present-in-kallsyms) removed which is why it doesn't show up here. However, to make things a bit more ***spicy***(ahem), I call the `__init` function as part of the `__exit` routine. Here are the kernel messages I get when I unload my module:

```
Mar 19 17:27:28 aijazVM kernel: [22750.453020] "Hello world exit, let's try calling init here"
Mar 19 17:27:28 aijazVM kernel: [22750.453023] "Hello world initialization!"
```

It is rather strange that I do not have the symbol for the `__init` function present, yet I can still call that function from within the file. What comes to my mind is, perhaps the relevant memory (more like cache lines) have not yet been invalidated so it's possible that I just get lucky? After all since it is the same translation unit, references to this function from within the file would all be offset based.

However I tried flushing the cache just to see if this could panic the kernel but seems to have no effect.

```
Mar 19 18:01:33 aijazVM kernel: [24795.884795] "Hello world initialization!"
Mar 19 18:02:01 aijazVM kernel: [24823.169160] echo (15514): drop_caches: 3
Mar 19 18:02:12 aijazVM kernel: [24834.528229] "Hello world exit, let's try calling init here"
Mar 19 18:02:12 aijazVM kernel: [24834.528232] "Hello world initialization!"
```

Is there a way to force the cpu to invalidate the entire cache hierarchy? Is there an architecture agnostic way to achieve this aka tell the process(ors) to invalidate their local caches (L1/L2/L3) safely without shooting ourselves in the foot?

Comment: Why do you think these *should* make sense for loadable modules?  There's a whole universe of nonsensical things that you can do.

Comment: As far as I know, the linker will blame a usage of `__init` function in non-init code. Since you don't have any warning, my guess is that compiler simply inlines the **code** of `helloworld_init` function into the `helloworld_exit` one. This would explain why you don't have a crash at runtime. For determine, whether inlining had a place, you need to inspect the disassembled module's code. In any case, calling `__init` function from `__exit` code is simply wrong. If you want to call `helloworld_init` from `helloworld_exit`, then do not mark the former with `__init` attribute.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm doing this deliberately as a sort of an experiment. I suspected the same about the linker throwing up which is why I'm using the script. I'll check the disassembly.

Comment: The compiler optimizes that away, because it's called only once from a single place. Try something different.

Comment: Yes it was indeed getting inlined. Now after forcing the compiler to _not_ inline the routine, I get an OOPs as expected